# How to solve "NoSuchElementException" error?

Tags: python, parsing, selenium

I've started to wrote a parser for a local real estate site. I've used Selenium to select the page that I need but after a couple of minutes I cannot reach it one more time, it gives me this error:

```
    NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="tr_an-357543"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64)
```

This is the piece of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://makler.md/md/"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window() 

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rublist_lev1"]/li[1]/a').click() # acces Imobiliare
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Vânzare apartamente, camere").click() # acces Apartamente

parentElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tr_an-357543"]')
elementList = parentElement.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

links = []

for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//article[starts-with(@id, "tr_an-")]//a[@class="ls-detail_anUrl"]'):
    links.append(element.get_attribute('href'))


page = driver.get(links[15])

caracteristici = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="anItemData"]/ul[2]')# Selecteaza blocul caracteristici
print(caracteristici.text)

driver.close()
```

when I copy-paste the x path for 'caracteristici' one more time, it's working. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Does the `id` change for this element `'//*[@id="tr_an-357543"]'`? It sounds like you just need some more robust selectors. It's hard to say what those might look like without seeing any `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it takes few seconds for the site to load each page. You can define implicitly wait when you initialize the `driver` to wait up to the given time for the elements to exist in the DOM when searching for them (one time initialization)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Or use explicit wait and `expected_conditions` in the problematic parts

```
parentElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tr_an-357543"]'))
```

For reference [waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).